# Esperar hasta el Callback de onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema al comprobar el resultado del callback, cuando llamo onActivityResult() para obtener el resultado si el usuario permitio o cancelo la activacion de bluetooth, el programa no espera por el resultado de la decisión del usuario.

necesito que espere la respuesta para asi poder preguntar en el If correctamente.

```
public void iniciarBluetooth(){
    if(localBT == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: El dispositivo no cuenta con blueetoth integrado");
    }else if(!localBT.isEnabled()){
        Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: iniciando bluetooth");


        Intent iniciarBluetoothIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(iniciarBluetoothIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

        int resultado = 0;
        onActivityResult(REQUEST_ENABLE_BT, resultado, iniciarBluetoothIntent);

        if(resultado == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: Se encendera el bluetooth");
            switchBT.setText(getString(R.string.apagarBT));
        }else
            Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: Se cancelo la solicitud de encendido bluetooth");

    }else if(localBT.isEnabled()){
        Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: apagando bluetooth");
        localBT.disable();

        switchBT.setText(getString(R.string.encenderBT));
    }
}
```

Respuesta de Logcat

```
/com.example.refer.bluetooth D/MainActivity: iniciarBlueetooth: iniciando bluetooth
//No espera el resultado del callback y comprueba con el valor de inicializacion del Int resultado
/com.example.refer.bluetooth D/MainActivity: iniciarBlueetooth: Se cancelo la solicitud de encendido bluetooth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así no es como se usa un callback, necesitas dos métodos, el que ya tienes que inicia la actividad, y otro que será el callback, algo así:

```
public void iniciarBluetooth(){
    if(localBT == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: El dispositivo no cuenta con blueetoth integrado");
    }else if(!localBT.isEnabled()){
        Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: iniciando bluetooth");

        Intent iniciarBluetoothIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(iniciarBluetoothIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

    }else if(localBT.isEnabled()){
        Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: apagando bluetooth");
        localBT.disable();

        switchBT.setText(getString(R.string.encenderBT));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: Se encendera el bluetooth");
        switchBT.setText(getString(R.string.apagarBT));
    }else
        Log.d(TAG, "iniciarBlueetooth: Se cancelo la solicitud de encendido bluetooth");

}
```

Te recomiendo estudiar un poquito y mirarte que es un callback: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming) [Ingles]